# Edit my textfile to only show highest value?

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I use the following coding which edits my text file based on the value in column being smaller than the value in a textbox.

```
Dim intValue As Integer
        Dim intMaxValue As Integer = Integer.Parse(textbox1.Text)

        Dim strSourceFile As String = IO.Path.Combine("G:\test.txt")
        Dim OutPutFile As String = IO.Path.Combine("G:\test2.txt")

        Dim strLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(strSourceFile)
        Dim strFiltered As New System.Text.StringBuilder
        Dim strTemp() As String

        For Each strLine In strLines
            If strLine.Trim.Length <> 0 Then
                strTemp = strLine.Split(" "c)
                If Trim(strTemp(0)) = "USER" AndAlso Trim(strTemp(2)) = "1" Then
                    strLine = strTemp(8).Trim & " " & strTemp(16).Trim
                    If Integer.TryParse(strLine.Split(" "c)(1), intValue) Then
                        If intValue <= intMaxValue Then
                            strFiltered.Append(strLine & Environment.NewLine)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        Next

        IO.File.WriteAllText(OutPutFile, strFiltered.ToString)
```

Now the above coding works perfectly, the output looks like the following:-

```
String1 100
String1 256
String1 500
String2 100
String2 256
String3 876
String3 345
String3 643
String3 102
String4 100
String4 084
String5 492
String5 178
String6 873
String6 156
String6 786
```

What I was hoping for was to add additional coding so i only want the String with the highest number showing so the above would look like

```
String1 500
String2 256
String3 876
String4 100
String5 492
String6 873
```

Would it be possible to add the final bit of coding?

**UPDATE**

Rather than checking the highest number and deleting the other fields, I wish to check each matching field in column 1 and check the highest number and if its greater than the field in textbox1 then remove all rows for that matching fields in column 1. If the highest number is lower than the field in textbox1, then keep that row but remove the other column 1 matching fields. So for example

```
String1 100
String1 256
String1 500
String2 100
String2 256
String3 876
String3 345
String3 643
String3 102
String4 100
String4 084
String5 492
String5 178
String6 873
String6 156
String6 786
```

So if textbox1 was to have 550 then you should have

```
String1 500
String2 256
String4 100
String5 492
```

**Update 2**

The value in textbox1 is

```
1341273599
```

When I only filter the columns to show column 1 and column 2 I get the following.

```
S00048 1428142557
S00048 1428141809
S00048 1338805621
S00048 1310295931
S00048 1309086124
S00048 1432203954
S00048 1431686625
S00048 1428142556
S00048 1431686626
S00048 1334743408
S00042 1324204635
S00040 1313659927
S00037 1308388943
S00033 1303118141
S00032 1391422317
S00032 1391422304
S00032 1298024019
S00032 1391422303
S00032 1391422316
```

So when I run the actual coding I get the following

```
S00048 1338805621
S00042 1324204635
S00040 1313659927
S00037 1308388943
S00033 1303118141
S00032 1298024019
```

You might be able to see that the end result is incorrect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a Dictionary to hold the values:

```
    Dim FilteredDictionary as new Dictionary(string, integer)

    Dim intValue As Integer
    Dim intMaxValue As Integer = Integer.Parse(textbox1.Text)

    Dim strSourceFile As String = IO.Path.Combine("G:\test.txt")
    Dim OutPutFile As String = IO.Path.Combine("G:\test2.txt")

    Dim strLines() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(strSourceFile)
    Dim strFiltered As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim strTemp() As String

    Dim lastIntValue as integer = 0
    For Each strLine In strLines
        If strLine.Trim.Length <> 0 Then
            strTemp = strLine.Split(" "c)
            If Trim(strTemp(0)) = "USER" AndAlso Trim(strTemp(2)) = "1" Then
                strLine = strTemp(8).Trim & " " & strTemp(16).Trim
                If Integer.TryParse(strLine.Split(" "c)(1), intValue) Then
                      If intValue = 0 Then
                        intValue=lastIntValue
                      Else
                        lastIntValue=intValue
                      End If
                      If FilteredDictionary.ContainsKey(strTemp(8).Trim) then
                        If intValue > FilteredDictionary(strTemp(8).Trim) then
                          FilteredDictionary(strTemp(8).Trim) = intValue
                        End If
                      Else
                        FilteredDictionary.Add(strTemp(8).Trim, intValue)
                      End If
                        'strFiltered.Append(strLine & Environment.NewLine)

                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Modifed stringbuilder to only add those items that are less than or equal to
    'a given value in Textbox1.  Note that if Textbox1 is not an integer,
    'it will throw an error.  You could use Integer.TryParse instead.
    For Each item As String in FilteredDictionary.Keys.ToList
       If FilteredDictionary(item) <= Convert.ToInt32(Textbox1.Text)
         strFiltered.AppendLine(item & " " & FilteredDictionary(item))
       EndIf
    Next
    IO.File.WriteAllText(OutPutFile, strFiltered.ToString)
```

Comment: Hi Holger are you about? I could do with a little help please.  Or we could take it to chat?

Comment: Sure, let's take it to chat.  Let me know the name of chat room.

Comment: Holger, sorry i cant go into chat because It says I have not got enough reputation??  I will edit the first post and let you know the problem I have.

Comment: So, if I understand your latest update, you are looking for user records that do not exceed a specified value, in this case 550.  However, wouldn't String3 still return 345?  I am a little confused when looking at your results.

Comment: Hi, no it wouldnt as String3 has 643 which is higher than 550.  So all Strings that are higher than 550 I want to remove the group ie String1, String2, String3 and (as previously) only have the highest value showing from the ones less than 550.

Comment: I think I got it.  I modified that last section that builds the string.  If a "String" is larger than Textbox1.Text value, then it won't be included in the result string.

Comment: Thanks Holger, I have tried the coding but if the value in textbox1 is higher then its not removing all the matching rows?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13314/discussion-between-holger-brandt-and-jacksparrow)

Comment: Holger I have a quick question, I have also messaged you in chat? please let me know when you are next available.